# Problem with 'when' statement in VHDL, Vivado

Tags: vhdl

I have a design in which there is a input of (5 downto 0) and an output of a single bit. I want the output to be '1' when the input is "111111" and '0' when the input is not "111111". So I used the 'when' statement. There are 3 types of codes but all of them show the same errors such as < **Error: this construct is only supported in VHDL 1076-2008** >. How can I modify the code in order to remove this error? (My code is down below.)

Thanks for your help.

```
-- type 1
output <= '1' when (input="111111") else '0';

-- type 2
output <= '1' when (input = (input'range => '1')) else '0';

-- type 3
output <= '1' when (input = (input'high downto input'low => '1')) else '0';
```

Comment: And yet you can produce a [mcve] containing all three **conditional signal assignment statements**  [analyzes, elaborates and simulates successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XAqZ.jpg). Without providing the means for your readers to reproduce the problem one might suspect you're trying to use a  conditional signal assignment  in a place suitable for a sequential statement (e.g. a subprogram or process statement) where prior to -2008 conditional signal assignment and selected signal assignment statements were only concurrent statements.

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008 10. Sequential statements, 10.5.3 Conditional signal assignments, first paragraph "The conditional signal assignment represents an equivalent if statement that assigns values to signals or that forces or releases signals." Without seeing a [mcve] it may be possible to make the assignment(s) concurrent statements as well.

Comment: Your code is not complete as noted by @user1155120, so we can not help here. I suspect from the error message 2 things: 1. you should enable VHDL-2008 support in your tool. 2. you're using a concurrent statement in a sequential statement region (e.g. process). As a shorter solution you could just write `output <= and input;`, but this also requires VHDL-2008 support to get the unary `and` operator.

Comment: You cannot use a `when`-`else` statement inside a `process` unless you enable VHDL-2008. My recommendation would be to convert these to `if` statements.